# How to get the project name when using TFS custom plugins

Tags: tfs, custom-controls

When we write C# code for a custom TFS plugin, we are capturing the check-in event.  How can we retrieve the project name the user is checking in to?

Comment: What do you mean by 'project': the *.csproj, the TeamProject or something else? What would you do if pending changeset contains stuff from different projects?

Answer (score 2):

The Team Project name is always the first portion of the path.  For example, if a user checks in a file to:

```
$/ExampleProject/Folder/File.txt
```

Then the Team Project name is `ExampleProject`.  The TFS SDK has a helper method that will allow you to get the Team Project name given a source control path:

```cs
string teamProjectName = 
    VersionControlPath.GetTeamProjectName("$/ExampleProject/Folder/File.txt");
```

Note that you can check into multiple team projects at the same time.  For example, your pending changes can contain changes to:

```
$/Project1/Folder/File.txt
$/Project2/Folder/File.txt
```

In which case, the user is checking into both `Project1` and `Project2`.

Answer (score 1):

When capturing the Checkin-event using a plugin for TFS 2010 and you loop thru all the CheckinNotification properties (notificationEventArgs as CheckinNotification) I get.....
**Changeset,
Comment,
ComputerName,
NotificationInfo,
Options,
CheckinNote,
PolicyOverrideInfo,
ChangesetOwnerName,
WorkspaceOwnerName,
WorkspaceName,
CheckinType,
SubmittedItems,
HasAllItems**

The submitted items is a collection, just loop thru the collection...

```
string myitem="";
CheckinNotification data = notificationEventArgs as CheckinNotification;
if (data != null)
{                  
Type type = data.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] myproperties = type.GetProperties();
if (property.Name == "SubmittedItems")
{
foreach (var checkin in data.SubmittedItems)
myitem = checkin.ToString(); 
}
}  
}
```

This will give you all the files that have been checked in. This is only partial code, you need to find the example from nielshebling.de titled TFS 2010: Using plugins to register an event